# Georeference not Aligning

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

In QGIS - When I georeference the image, it does not line up.  How to resolve?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What GIS software are you using? lt also looks like Alaska is included on the image? I would edit the source image and remove it. As the top-left is the origin and each pixel resolution is calculated from that.

Comment: QGIS.   Ok I'll delete the extraneous and try again.  Thanks!

Comment: 2nd attempt still not aligned....I updated images above in post to illustrate.

Comment: is the original image available online? Do you know the projections for both the data and image? They need to match first before geo-referencing.

Comment: https://www.energy.gov/eere/femp/rainwater-availability-landscape-irrigation-map  ORIG here.

Comment: I set the image to the same projection: 4326-WGS84

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raster you want to georeference most probably uses the `EPSG:2163`, USA National Atlas CRS.

You should set this as your project CRS and target projection.

And also use `Thin Plate Spline` transformation method, with a significant number of reference points:

[image]

[image]

This is the result of a first attempt, you should be able to reach a pretty good result with additional points:

[image]

Comment: Acknowledging this is the correct answer for the original question posted. Though data is available online via ArcGIS as I discovered.

Comment: How did you determine that the image probably uses the EPSG:2163, USA National Atlas CRS.

Comment: I saw it had a particular projection, not one we find in web maps, I recalled having seen US maps in this representation. Searching for 'US maps projection' brought me here : https://datacarpentry.org/organization-geospatial/03-crs/index.html

Comment: Nice. Thx for the link.

Answer (score 2):

The data you require is in available in ArcGIS REST
you can use QGIS to read this dataset using the ArcGIS REST Connection

```
https://services7.arcgis.com/F8VN7MYN9lP1oiiV/ArcGIS/rest/services/FEMP_Alternative_Water_Source_Data/FeatureServer
```

In QGIS
you can view the data to county level.
[image]

Comment: How did you find the data?

Comment: Federal Energy Management Program (FEMP) from the link you provided.

Comment: Cool.  Thx again!